# access rails server from multiple machines

Tags: ruby-on-rails, linux, ubuntu

I run a rails server `rails server -b 10.0.0.2 -p 3001` on my linux machine, so people in my office can access it from the ip above.

I want to make it possible to connect to this server from other machines, and from my own PC as well (with `localhost:3001`).

Any ideas how can I create a situation that both 10.0.0.2:3001 and localhost:3001 works with a single `rails server` command?

Comment: If `10.0.0.2` is your IP and your colleagues are in an accessable network, you should just need to allow port 3001 through your firewall.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to bind on 0.0.0.0.

`rails server -b 0.0.0.0 -p 3001`